# Plot the route of ships using Leaflet.js | Polyline

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, maps, polyline

*I have a dataset that consists of AIS messages for a number of ships, representing the route they have follow for a period of time. The dataset was in .csv form and I have upload it to a mongodb.
I want to create a polyline on leaflet.js map for each one of the ships but my approach suffers in terms of performance. Any better ideas???*

**My Approach**
I use node.js with express for my backend and I stream the data to the server using the mongoose cursor API when the client side ask for them (clientReady event). The data reach to the client through a websocket implemented with socket.io

```
socket.on('clientReady', () => {
console.log('Data stream to client initiated');
cursor = model.shipModel.find({}).lean().cursor();
cursor.on('data', (doc) => {
  socket.emit('data', doc);
  cursor.pause();
  socket.on('moreData', () => {
    cursor.resume();
  });
});
```

I pause the cursor after the server has sent the first data to the client, in order to create a slower dataflow towards the client.
When client emits "moreData" event the cursor continues for the next data and then it pauses again.

I create a Map where I store each ship as an object, and each object has an array field where I keep the coordinates of the route. I create a polyline for each ship for the initial coordinates and every time an additional pair of coordinates for a particular ship arrives, I have to search the Map for this ship in order to update the coordinates array, which then I pass to the leaflet polyline to refresh it as well.

```
  var mapShips = (ship) => {
  let element = ships.get(ship.MMSI);
  if (typeof element != 'undefined') {
    let latlng = [ship.LAT, ship.LON];
    element.coordinates.push(latlng);
    refreshPolyline(element.shipPolyline, element.coordinates);
  } else {
    let newShip = {};
    newShip.coordinates = [];
    let latlng = [ship.LAT, ship.LON];
    newShip.coordinates.push(latlng);
    newShip.shipPolyline = new L.polyline([latlng], {
      smoothFactor: 1,
      color: color,
      className: 'polylineStyle'
    }).addTo(map);
    ships.set(ship.MMSI, newShip);
  }
};
```

- **ships** is a global Map variable that holds the ship objects
- **ship** is the new ship information that is used to refresh the polyline